# Is there an implementation of forward mapping/warping in a neural network framework?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch

## Introduction

I want to train a neural network and require a differentiable implementation of a forward mapping to warp a source image into a destination image, see e.g. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/warp/warp.pdf.

What I already found is backward mapping via pytorch (grid_sample), in which every pixel in destination image has only a single connection to one particular pixel in source image (+ neighbours).

## Code

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create artificial image
im = np.zeros((9,9)) 
im[4,4] = 1

# warping images
u = np.zeros((9,9))
v = np.zeros((9,9))

u[4,3] += 1


# shift to pytorch
h,w = np.shape(im)

im_t = torch.from_numpy(im).float().view((1,1,h,w)).cpu()
u_t = torch.from_numpy(u).float().view((1,h,w,1)).cpu()
v_t = torch.from_numpy(v).float().view((1,h,w,1)).cpu()


n, _, h, w = im_t.size()
batchSize, _, _, nmbSamples = im_t.size()

# warp source image
U = torch.arange(start=0, end=w).expand(h, w).float().view((n, h, w, 1)).cpu()
V = torch.arange(start=0, end=h).expand(w, h).t().float().view((n, h, w, 1)).cpu()

U_u = (U + u_t) / ((w-1) / 2) - 1
V_v = (V + v_t) / ((h-1) / 2) - 1

grid = torch.cat((U_u, V_v), dim=3).float().cpu()

warped_t = F.grid_sample(im_t, grid)

# plot routine
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(im_t.data.cpu().numpy()[0,0,:,:])
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(warped_t.data.cpu().numpy()[0,0,:,:])
plt.grid()

plt.show(block=False)
plt.draw()
```

## Problem

What I need, is to render the destination image from different, non neighbouring pixels in source image.

Help appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an existing forward warping method in PyTorch. Forward warping inevitably brings in problems such as many-to-one correspondence and zero correspondence. These problems need to be addressed based on the problem setup.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation for forward mapping can also be done by grid_sample by using as a grid a the positions of the image + the displacement

```
def forward(self, tensorInput, tensorFlow):
    if hasattr(self, 'tensorGrid') == False or self.tensorGrid.size(0) != tensorFlow.size(0) or self.tensorGrid.size(2) != tensorFlow.size(2) or self.tensorGrid.size(3) != tensorFlow.size(3):
        torchHorizontal = torch.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, tensorFlow.size(3)).view(1, 1, 1, tensorFlow.size(3)).expand(tensorFlow.size(0), 1, tensorFlow.size(2), tensorFlow.size(3))
        torchVertical = torch.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, tensorFlow.size(2)).view(1, 1, tensorFlow.size(2), 1).expand(tensorFlow.size(0), 1, tensorFlow.size(2), tensorFlow.size(3))

        self.tensorGrid = torch.cat([ torchHorizontal, torchVertical ], 1).cuda()
    # end

    tensorFlow = torch.cat([ tensorFlow[:, 0:1, :, :] / ((tensorInput.size(3) - 1.0) / 2.0), tensorFlow[:, 1:2, :, :] / ((tensorInput.size(2) - 1.0) / 2.0) ], 1)

    return torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(input=tensorInput, grid=(self.tensorGrid + tensorFlow).permute(0, 2, 3, 1), mode='bilinear', padding_mode='border')
```

There exists also a differentiable forward warp's lib https://github.com/lizhihao6/Forward-Warp

About the flow/displacement (if it's just a disparity it's easier), if you have different images in different positions, probably you have the rotation matrix between the views (extrinsics) and camera info (intrinsics) and also you need the depth. Since you asked about forward mapping I'll assume the source viewpoint depth: the displacement is found projecting the depth values in world coordinates, applying the transformation in space, unprojection in pixel coordinates.